# how to build a table in html from an array in email in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to generate an email in PHP using the data collected by Javascript and passed to PHP file in an array.

The array in js looks basically like this

```
 Menu[
     item(name,price,multiplier[],ingred),
     item(name,price,multiplier[],ingred)
     ]
```

the array Menu[] is created dynamically and then passed through the $.ajax call

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'sendEmail.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
                emailTo: emailToVal, 
                tel: telVal,
                subject: subjectVal, 
                message: messageVal,
                mijnMenu: JSON.stringify(mijnMenu)},
```

I need to build a table from the data of the array and send an email. I cannot figure out how to build the rows of the table.

my PHP script is

```
    $body = "<p>Hi,</p>";
    $body .= "<p>I have received your mail....</p>;"
    $body .= "<p>Your menu :</p>";
    $body .= "<table style='border: 1px black solid; width: 80%;'><tbody>";

    if (isset($_POST["myMenu"])) {
            $myMenu = json_decode($_POST["myMenu"]);

            foreach($myMenu as $row){
            $row = "<tr><td>". $myMenu=>name ."</td><td>". $myMenu=>price."</td><td>". $myMenu=>multiplier[1]. "</td></tr>";
            $body .= $row;
            }
    }
    $body .= "</tbody></table>";
    $body .= "</body></html>";
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're reusing the variable `$row` -- first it's the element of `$myMenu`, then you're also using it as the string for the table row.

Comment: why don't you create the HTML table on the Javascript side instead of the PHP side?

Comment: `$myMenu=>name` should be `$row->name`.

Comment: Eric, I need to collect the data from the user and send it to his/her e-mail. Is there a way to build an emal in js and pas it to the PHP script to send it as an e-mail? Woud it be a better way then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foreach` loop should be:

```
foreach($myMenu as $row){
    $tr = "<tr><td>". $row->name ."</td><td>". $row->price."</td><td>". $row->multiplier[1]. "</td></tr>";
    $body .= $tr;
}
```

You were using the wrong syntax for accessing an object property (`=>` instead of `->`), and you were also accessing the wrong variable -- `$myMenu` is the array of all menu items, while `$row` is  the current item in the loop. And you were also using the same variable `$row` for both the iteration and the temporary string being added to `$body`.